# Is there a way to show with markdown how many tickets aren't completed yet in azure?

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, markdown

Is there a way to show with markdown (*readme.md*) how many tickets aren't completed yet in azure devops?

I want to show something like `"17/20 tickets done"` in the *readme.md* file.

Comment: To do this in a source-controlled `.md`, you would need some kind of a bot with git access to watch for ticket status changes and then contribute a PR with the changes to the `.md`. Possible, but I'm not aware of anything that can do it.

Comment: @Goldflash Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the status badge feature from the kanban board settings. Have a look at [Configure status badges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/configure-status-badges?view=azure-devops) to get results like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes I found this too, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, write a query or use an existing one then invoke it using the REST API and your favorite programming Language.

You can use powershell and a powershell task as part of the build/release pipeline. From the output of the query, you need to create / update the readme with this content.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1